# pytesseract Error on python3 FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using python 3.4 on my 64 bit windows 8.1 machine. I've already successfully installed pytesseract 0.1.6 and Pillow 3.0.0. Here is my code :

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('test.png')
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
```

and `test.png` is in the same folder as the project is. I've also tried JPG image format but i got the same problem.

Here is the error code:

`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

What should i do to avoid this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: use an absolute path instead of a relative path, that will probably change things

Comment: When i use `img.show()` there is no problem and the image will be opened successfully. What do you mean by "reading" the message error? @Ahsanul

Comment: I need to mention that the error is corresponding to the line includes `print` . I tried absolute address also but the problem is not with the `open` . @RNar

Comment: that can still cause an error, reminder that `Image.open()` is a [lazy operator](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm) that only checks for validity of the file when the file is actually being processed, not when you declare it

Comment: Then what should i do? @RNar

Comment: well first, recheck if that file really does exist. other than that, change it to its absolute path, ie if its inside of your documents folder in your main hard drive, for example, it would be something like `C:\Users\me\Documents\test.png`

Comment: There is no problem with the file and the address! I think there is a problem with the `pytesseract` only function `image_to_string()` . I do not have any OS other than windows right now! If anyone does i would appreciate them if they check this on their own OS!

Comment: my bad OP, just trying to help ya out. [this link](https://code.google.com/p/pytesser/issues/detail?id=2) may help you out, seems like a common problem. the last solution (opening the file and changing the import) seems like the easiest fix

Comment: oh! Thanks! It works! :) @RNar